# Why doesn't this gravatar-generated image work on IOS?

Tags: ios, gravatar

I'm using gravatar to generate avatars like so:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/516d060859b00e099588610cfd973432?s=64&d=retro" width="32" height="32">
```

Works great on desktops, all browsers. But results in a broken image on IOS (e.g. iPhone). Any idea how I get it this to work for IOS?

Comment: Do you mean in the `UIWebView`?

Comment: Hi, I just mean in Safari. As in, when HTML containing that IMG tag is loaded up on an iPhone, it doesn't work. But the same HTML works fine on desktops etc.

Comment: Maybe internet connection issue?

Comment: Nope. Everything else on the page loads fine. It's just the image that's broken.